# How to add multiple values in single variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get multiple values in a single variable like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

```js
$('.icon').click(function() {
  var totalWishlist;
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  totalWishlist += $(this).attr('data-pid');
  console.log(totalWishlist);          
});
```

```css
.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon" data-pid="1">icon 1</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="2">icon 2</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="3">icon 3</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="4">icon 4</div>
```

Why am I getting `undefined`?

Comment: Arrays are intended for exactly this purpose

Comment: You forgot to initialize `totalWishlist` to anything, so `+=`ing anything to it won't work (you should also coerce the attribute to a number)

Comment: Not only so, OP is overwriting `totalWishlist` in the click handler.

Comment: Also, `var totalWishlist` should be outside `$('.icon').click(function() {})`

Comment: i defined this like `var totalWishlist;` in code.

Comment: It is declared, but not initialized. It exists, but is still `undefined`. It is different from `var totalWishlist = "";`

Comment: Arrays are best way to do this

Comment: can the variable be a string?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `undefined1` etc. because you don't declare `totalWishlist` with a value, so by default it's undefined. To fix that, define it as an empty string *outside* of the click handler:

```
var totalWishlist = '';
```

*However*, it would make far more sense to use an array and `push()` to it. This is far easier to modify. If you want to retrieve a string from that array you can use `join(', ')`, like this:

```js
var totalWishlist = [];

$('.icon').click(function() {
  totalWishlist.push($(this).data('pid'));
  console.log(totalWishlist.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon" data-pid="1">icon 1</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="2">icon 2</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="3">icon 3</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="4">icon 4</div>
```

Comment: i don't need  array, we cant do it without array?

Comment: Using an array makes the solution to your problem much easier to work with and far less hacky. If you want to get a string back out of the array just use `join(',')`

Comment: @RohitVerma It does not matter. What you want is to store a "collection" of the pid, and array is the best way to do it. If you want to create the string `1, 2, 3, 4` later, you can simply join the array, e.g.. `totalWishList.join(', ')`

Comment: @RohitVerma You don't know how to store multiple values in a single variable, but you know you don't need arrays? Interesting

Comment: @JeremyThille indeed. This is a very odd question as the OP has historically asked (and even answered) questions on much more complex topics than basic array use. This seems almost like a shared account, or one which has been illegitimately accessed.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i edit my question, actually i also want to remove count when deselect class.

Comment: I would start a new question about that as it's entirely different from what you originally asked

Answer (score 1):

**Use an array and move it outside of your function**. If you want to add the items only once, use `includes` to check if the item is already in the array and skip it:

```js
const totalWishlist = [];

$('.icon').click(function() {
  const pid = $(this).attr('data-pid');
  if (!totalWishlist.includes(pid)) {
    totalWishlist.push(pid);
  }
  console.log(...totalWishlist);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon" data-pid="1">icon 1</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="2">icon 2</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="3">icon 3</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="4">icon 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable an string And define it outside the function. Make it global.

```js
var totalWishlist="";
$('.icon').click(function() {
    
    
      totalWishlist+=$(this).attr('data-pid')+ " ";
      console.log(totalWishlist);
      
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon" data-pid="1">icon 1</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="2">icon 2</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="3">icon 3</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="4">icon 4</div>
```

Or make it an array

```js
var totalWishlist=[];
$('.icon').click(function() {
    
    
      totalWishlist.push($(this).attr('data-pid'));
      console.log(totalWishlist);
      
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon" data-pid="1">icon 1</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="2">icon 2</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="3">icon 3</div>
<div class="icon" data-pid="4">icon 4</div>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to concatenate the values, not sum them up.

Comment: `multiple values like this 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, doesn't seem to me like OP wants to concatenate them